# Monte Carlo simulation in Power BI using Azure DevOps/Jira data

Tags: powerbi, forecasting, montecarlo, agile

I previously had a monte carlo simulation built into my free flow metrics template for agile teams who use Azure DevOps/Jira to use in Power BI (attached)

[image]

Recently the visual (using the D3 visual) has started to face performance issues, particular in the web service.

Does anyone know how to create a monte carlo simulation in Power BI for forecasting number of items/delivery dates? It's beyond my skillset (previous version was coded by a friend)

Working version without using D3 visual